# How can I populate select boxes with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, aramex

I'm setting up a jqGrid which needs to visualize multiple values in one cell. The input comes from a form where the user can select multiple choices. I am able to display the select box, but not populate it. I have tried to insert an array in the JSON object, but to no success.

This is the model:

```
index:'ship', editoptions:{multiple:true, value:{1:”FedEx”,2:”InTime”,3:”TNT”,4:”ARAMEX”}}
```

And here are some variations of the data I've tried populating with:

```
ship:{[1],[4]}
ship:[[1],[4]]
ship:{value:{1,4}}
```

...and lots of other variations.

I've also searched the jqGrid forum, but didn't find a solution. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy!

I had the answer all the time. It was just as easy as I had hoped it would be.

Here's how it's done:

```
ship:["FedEx","TNT"]
```

The reason for why I didn't think it worked is because jqGrid shows the data as "FedEx, TNT", thus making me believe it was only a string. Instead of clicking the cell to see what had happend, I spent hours looking for the answer on the internet. If you'd like to know what happends; jqGrid renders a select list with both elements selected. Simple.

Happy jqGrid'ing!